# AMD RaidXpert2 / Ryzen (X570) - Windows 10 - How to automount array?

Tags: windows-10, raid, automount, amd-ryzen

The problem is very simple.

If you use RAIDXpert2 - so AMD's in-built RAID utility - the array will NOT auto-mount after a reboot.
On each reboot I have to open the RAIDXpert2 utility, click `Disk -> Rescan` and then my normal NTFS filesystem shows up that I created on the array.

How could I auto-mount it on each boot? Is there a setting for it somewhere?
Or should I just do like a CLI command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I found a **workaround.**

- Make a new Task Scheduler Basic task.
- The program you need to call is: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\RAIDXpert2\rcadm.exe"`
- Arguments: `-M -rsc`
- Set it to "At System Startup".
- Once you are in the properties of this new task, set it to: "Run whether user is logged on or not" AND "Run with highest privileges".

Save. Reboot, it should now re-add your array on reboot seamlessly.
Uploaded the pictures here if that makes things easier to see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pln9H.jpg